# Basic auth Apache and multiple IP conditions

Tags: apache-2.4

Apache Basic auth, with multiple IP conditions, works with this [way](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html), but according to [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html), I should be able to write something like this `.htaccess` sample (the bellowing IP addresses are written for the sake of the question):

```
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '1.1.1.1' || %{REMOTE_ADDR} != '8.8.8.8' || %{REMOTE_HOST} != 'example.com'">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "restricted area"
  AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
  require valid-user
</If>
```

But it does not work, as soon as I add more than one address and when I use  `||` or `&&`, etc… Indeed, Apache2 requires login from the above mentioned IP even if they should be allowed. But if I write only one of them, Apache allows access without login.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: (1) What do you mean, it doesn't work? (2) Your `If` condition is always true. (3) Is your `Require` statement in a directory context? Or is this a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum this is a logic problem. You did not clearly expressed what is the expected result, though. So I'm half guessing.

Assuming you want this :

- domain=example => ok (no password)
- address=1... => ok (no password)
- address=8... => ok (no password)
- anything else => not ok (password needed)

You just need to concentrate on the "ok" part. The expression that is true for all these conditions is

```
a=1 || a=8 || d=example
```

Now, you need to do nothing in this case, but for all other cases, you need to do something (ask password), so you have to reverse the test. The needed expression becomes

```
not (a=1 || a=8 || d=example)
```

Developping `not (a=1 || a=8 || d=exampe)` gives `(not (a=1)) && (not (a=8)) && (not d=example))` which you can be simplified as `a!=1 && a!=8 && d!=example`

So, try this :

```
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} != '1.1.1.1' && %{REMOTE_ADDR} != '8.8.8.8' && %{REMOTE_HOST} != 'example.com'">
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "restricted area"
  AuthUserFile /home/user/.htpasswd
  require valid-user
</If>
```

Comment: I really need some rest. Thanks for you detailed explanation.